# Which STL container(s)/algorithm(s) could I use to solve this?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stl, containers

I have an MFC project which, given an initial root path, iterates through every file, folder and subfolder, and subsequently displays each file to the user in a List Control. Since this can easily become a rather lengthy operation, I occasionally yield control to the operating system (via processing a single message pump queue), allowing each of the elements discovered thus far to be displayed. Now here comes the tricky part...

I would like to keep the elements sorted by their last known modification timestamps, which (I believe) would require some kind of insertion sorting technique. Since some elements may contain duplicate timestamps, but different file paths, and we would be sorting by timestamp (stored as an `std::string` in the format of `MM:DD:YY hh:mm`), a simple `std::vector` doesn't appear to do the job. Also, I would prefer to not keep the user waiting for the entire operation to complete before starting to sort the elements, since the amount of time to wait is unknown and like I stated above, could easily become lengthy enough to make any person impatient.

Lastly, I would need some way to keep the elements inserted into the List Control equally mapped to the sorting operations on the container, so the user can see the most recently modified contents (and subcontents) of the root path in real-time.

What would be the proper container(s) and algorithm(s) to use in order to achieve this?
Here's basically what I'm doing now:

```
void CFileSearchDlg::UpdateDirectoryList(std::string strRootPath)
{
    CFilesystem fs; // Helper class which uses C++11 <filesystem> to iterate through file path entries
    DWORD time = GetTickCount(); // Determines if we should yield control to the OS after a certain period of time
    m_listView.DeleteAllItems(); // Clears all current elements from the list view control

    /*
    // CFilesystem::Search() takes in a root path and a lambda expression, and executes the expression for each
    // element found within the root path, passing a basic_directory_entry<path> as a parameter to the lambda
    // expression, and will continue to parse until no entries are left (or until we return false)...
    */
    fs.Search(strRootPath, [&](CFilesystem::path_entry pe)
        {
            // This is primarily a Unicode project, so we need to convert the search results to an std::wstring
            std::string path = pe.path().string();
            std::wstring wpath;
            wpath.assign(path.begin(), path.end());

            // Get a Win32 handle to the file/folder, or display an error & exit
            auto hFile = CreateFileA(path.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, NULL, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to open file", path.c_str(), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                return false; // Stop parsing
            }

            // Get the date & time attributes of the file/folder, or display an error & exit
            TCHAR fileTime[MAX_PATH];
            ZeroMemory(&fileTime, sizeof(TCHAR)* MAX_PATH);
            auto ret = GetLastWriteTime(hFile, fileTime, MAX_PATH);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            if (!ret) {
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Failed to get date & time attributes", path.c_str(), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
                return false; // Stop parsing
            }
            std::wstring strTime(fileTime);

            /************************************************** 
            // THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC IS SUPPOSED TO HAPPEN //
            /*************************************************/
            InsertPathItem(m_listView, wpath, strTime); // ... But how?

            // Check if we should yield control to the operating system
            auto tick = GetTickCount();
            if (tick - time > 100) {
                YieldControl();
                time = tick;
            }

            // Continue to parse directory contents
            return true;
        }
    );
}
```

> ***EDIT*:**
>   The full answer appears to be a combination of galinette's (about the proper STL container), and foraidt's (about synchronizing the view with the data).

Comment: What's with the downvotes? It's a valid question for a specific scenario. At least leave a reason why you feel otherwise...

Comment: Would a std::map do the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a `std::multimap`, with the key type either an integer timestamp (the fastest way) or as you suggested a time string if the default string sort keeps the timestamp order (this is slower)

```
std::multimap<time_t, std::wstring>
```

or

```
std::multimap<std::string, std::wstring>
```

Insert with:

```
myFileMap.insert(std::pair<time_t, std::wstring>(time,wPath));
```

Comment: If anything, perhaps an `std::multimap` would work (since duplicate timestamps could exist), but then there's still the issue of keeping the items sorted in the List Control. Is there a way to know how & when an element is moved? i.e., _where_ to insert new elements into the control?

Comment: @MatteoItalia : I was editing the answer while you were commenting :)

Comment: Just for clarification... do you mean an `std::multimap`? I can't find any information on `std::multimapmap`...

Answer (score 2):

An [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) keeps its element sorted according to its Comparator.

Edit : you need to provide a strictly-less-than, deterministic Comparator (forgot the mathematical term). If multiple identical timestamps are a possibility, you need to disambiguate with another property (an id, for example).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well that's true, but come one, one second after I clicked "post" ? We have a serious vote sniper here :p

Comment: Hey, at least they're upvotes. My question got a couple downvotes within minutes of asking, without any reason left behind =P

Answer (score 1):

To **synchronize** the sorting of the MFC **control** with your **internal** data structure, you could try a virtual list: The key is using the `LVS_OWNERDATA` style. The list will then not store the item data by itself but call back into your code to get the information needed to display an item. This is where you can jump into your custom sorted container and retrieve the information.

The article ['Using virtual lists' on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists) appears to be pretty comprehensive.

Next, **sorting** itself. You can try a custom type that contains the text to display as well as the criterion to sort by in numeric format, e.g.:

```
struct item {
    std::string label;
    time_t mtime;
};
```

For performance reasons it may be useful to insert multiple items into a vector and then sort it once before you give control back to the OS. You'll have to *test* whether this actually works better than directly inserting into a sorted container though.

Anyway, to easily switch between container types, you can specify a sort functor that can be used as sort predicate (could probably be done more elegant with C++11 lambdas):

```
struct item_less {
    bool operator()(const item & a, const item & b) {
        return a.mtime < b.mtime;
    }
};
```

Use it like this:

```
std::set<item, item_less> a; // Automatic sorting
std::vector<item> b;
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), item_less()); // Manual sorting
```

Comment: +1 Between this and @galinette's answer, I believe i should have enough information here to solve my question. I would vote both as the answer if I could.

Comment: Is it truly practical to manually sort a container that (potentially) has hundreds of thousands (or more) of elements, every time a new element is found? When parsing over a root folder, AFAIK there's no telling how many elements there will be until the operation has actually completed. Which is why I need all new data to be insertion-sorted at run-time. To further complicate things, `std::multimap` does not conform to RandomAccessIterator, and the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback appears to utilize indexing... So how could my data be mapped to a corresponding CListCtrl element?

Comment: @RectangleEquals It *may* be beneficial to sort only once after inserting many elements instead of inserting each element according to the sort order. My gut feeling says it will at least not be slower. But this is something that depends a lot on your concrete situation and you have to try it to find out. A `vector` storing the items (not pointers to items) may also perform better due to spatial locality. You can also try a `deque` instead, which offers random access but does not require contiguous memory blocks, which could become important when memory is scarce and fragmented.