# Populating a List Control with the sorted contents of an `std::multimap`?

Tags: c++, winapi, stl, mfc, clistctrl

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773596/which-stl-containers-algorithms-could-i-use-to-solve-this), I need a way to access my data by index. But the data needs to be sorted by timestamp, contain a filepath as a value, and be displayed in real-time as new elements are discovered.

Considering that multiple files/folders could potentially contain an identical timestamp, I've decided to go with `std::multimap` as the container of choice to store my data. However, this complicates the process of populating my List Control, since `LVITEM::iItem` is an index value used to determine which element of data is to be displayed in a control with the `LVS_OWNERDATA` flag set (i.e., [virtual lists](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7891/Using-virtual-lists)).

I can't seem to find a way to access my data by index in order to get the timestamp keys & filepath values, so what could I do to correct this issue?

Comment: You don't need to access items by index. The [LVITEM structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760.aspx) has an `lParam` field. It is pointer-sized which allows you to store a pointer to any (custom) structure alongside each listview item.

Comment: Yes, but how could I map my data to it, if the timestamp and filepath are unknown at the time that the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message is called, without some form of indexing?

Comment: @IInspectable Perhaps we misunderstand each other. AFAIK, populating a virtual list requires the use of the [NMLVDISPINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774780%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, which contains an `LV_ITEM`, which contains an index `iItem` that prompts for that specific element of data. `LPARAM` doesn't appear to be of any use here, since my data is stored in an `std::multimap<time_t, std::wstring>` so that results are sorted by timestamp, and are adjoined with a corresponding filepath. AFAIK, this cannot be accessed by index... So how can `LPARAM` help?

Comment: You can access `LVITEM::lParam` from your `LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback. Have the `lParam` point to the object in memory, and you don't need a way to retrieve it. Storing the data in a `multimap` seems unnecessary: You can store the data right in your Listview control, and provide an appropriate predicate for sorting.

Comment: If you still wish to store the data in a `multimap` you can assign `LVITEM::lParam` a `const_iterator` to the respective item, if size- and alignment-restrictions allow, or a pointer to a newly created `const_iterator` object otherwise. So whenever you are passed an `LVITEM` structure, you now have access to the complete item data behind it. This applies to any callback that passes in an `LVITEM` argument.

Comment: A virtual listview doesnt store any data except the item count.

Comment: Well something else to note here is that iterating over the entire data set is by no means practical when a given root folder may possibly contain hundreds of thousands of elements (if not more), constantly being updated at run-time. This is why model-view & virtual lists are most appropriate here... Also, this still doesn't solve the issue of *what* or *how* to assign to `lParam`, and it also raises the question of *when* to do so, considering the MFC application receives the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` from the OS automatically upon control visibility.

Comment: Not sure if std::distance works with multimap but if so this could potentially give you an index. I have a feeling though you might be better off usind a vector.

Comment: @Rectangle: I just told you *what* to store in the `lParam`: A (pointer to a) `const_iterator` to the item in your `multimap`. Iterators in a `multimap` remain valid, until the referenced item is removed.

Comment: "The item" is the issue here when I say "what"

Comment: i.e.: A const_iterator to *what*? The OS asks "Hey, what should I display for element #X", and my answer to the OS is "An element of my data, accessed *somehow*, magically mapped to that Nth element in an appropriate fashion"?

Comment: Perhaps if you link me to an example where an index isn't used to map data to a virtual list, we'd understand each other better, considering how the purpose of a virtual list is (seemingly) for the OS to incrementally tell an application an index range to utilize

Comment: @IInspectable It seems you may be thinking that I'm manually handling the message pump in my application. This isn't the case. It's an MFC app, so my callback for `LVN_GETDISPINFO` is actually an event method. The data is populated elsewhere in code (namely, during `OnInitDialog`, right after a call to `ShowWindow`), and this operation can take *at least* several minutes to complete (sometimes hours, depending on filesystem hierarchy). So are you saying I should ignore all calls to the callback where `LPARAM` is null, and manually send a `LVN_GETDISPINFO` message each time a new path is found?

Comment: @JonathanPotter `std::distance` will give me the # of elements in my data, but does not reference an element. Since `std::multimap` does not conform to `RandomAccessIterator`, I also can't do something like `auto myElement = myData.begin() + index;` to retrieve a certain index. The complicated thing here is that multimaps appear to sort by key, which means that I would need to know the timestamp in order to display the timestamp and date, since the timestamp is what the data needs to be sorted by. This information, in order to be mapped to a CListCtrl, needs some way to be indexed... I'm lost.

Comment: @RectangleEquals The way I see it you have three options; use a vector to index your multimap, ditch the multimap and just use a vector that you sort at the end, or ditch the virtual listview.

Comment: @JonathanPotter All of those options appear to require iterating over the entire set of data, either multiple times (to keep it sorted, exponentially increasing time of operation), or once (after an unknown amount of time, leaving the user completely in the dark with nothing to look at). Depending on the root folder's sub-hierarchy, we could be talking several hours on certain filesystems. There's gotta be a clever way to solve this, which doesn't make the user wait too long due to unnecessary iterations over the set of data. FYI, this is a backup/restore info utility, so time is important.

Comment: @RectangleEquals So what you want is a magical container that sorts things in O(n) time and acts like a vector. Good luck with that :)

Comment: Not exactly... I need a means of collecting filesystem data, and displaying it to the user, sorted by particular file attributes, without making the user wait several hours to see any results whatsoever. It just so happens that in most cases, this software will likely be used on rather complex filesystem hierarchies, so to the user, it's already guaranteed that the full operation will take time. But that's no reason to force them to wait for the entire operation to complete before getting any sort of information whatsoever, especially when that information is constantly being updated.

Comment: Windows Explorer's search has this functionality, so I know it's possible

Comment: @RectangleEquals: Windows Search typically uses pre-processed indexes from the Indexing Service, switch scans and indexes your filesystem in the background while you are doing other things. In cases where Windows Search has to actually search the filesystem directly, there are lower-level APIs it can use to quickly access the underlying filesystem records instead of using slower higher-level APIs like `FindFirstFile()`. So searches are implemented to be fast.

Comment: @RectangleEquals: In your case, you will probably need a background thread to push new items into your `multimap` and trigger UI updates asynchronously. That will let the user see updates as they occur, as well as be able to cancel it (if you decide to support that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the content of a `std::multimap` by index directly.  But what you can do is store your sorted data in a `std::multimap` and then store `iterator` values in a separate `std::vector` and use that as the data source for your ListView.  When the ListView asks for data by index, go to your `std::vector` and use the `iterator` at the specified index to access your data in the `std::multimap`.  When you `insert()` a new item in a `std::multimap()`, it returns an `iterator` for that item, and existing `iterator`s are not invalidated by inserts.

```
std::multimap<MyItemData> mydata;
std::vector<std::multimap<MyItemData>::iterator> lvdata;

...

std::multimap<MyItemData>::iterator iter = mydata.insert(...);
lvdata.push_back(iter);
SendMessage(hwndLV, LVM_SETITEMCOUNT, lvdata.size(), LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL | LVSICF_NOSCROLL);

...

case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
{
    NMLVDISPINFO *pdi = reinterpret_cast<NMLVDISPINFO*>(lParam);
    std::multimap<MyItemData>::iterator iter = lvdata[pdi->item.iItem];
    // use *iter as needed...
    break;
}
```

Comment: Marking this as the answer because (although it does not solve my particular sorting issue), it works as advertised, and is a direct answer to the question. Keep in mind that It slightly defeats the purpose of using an `std::multimap` in the first place. Something to note for MFC applications, is you would merely need to call [SetItemCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88tba5s4.aspx) in order to dispatch the message, triggering the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` method event. When `LVS_OWNERDATA` style is set (for the use of virtual lists), this message will not be dispatched automatically.